# Setting json string in http requests in Perl

Tags: python, rest, perl, put

Following Perl code generates an error printed below:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;

my $token = 'my token';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(PUT => "endpoint");
$req->header( 'Authorization' => "Bearer $token" );
$req->content_type('application/json');
$req->content('{"text":"whiteboard"}');
 
my $res = $ua->request($req);     
if ($res->is_success) {
    my $content = $res->decoded_content;
    my $fromjson = from_json($content);
    print Dumper $fromjson->{'results'}; 
}
else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
    print $res->content, "\n";
}
```

Error:

```
 {"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"str type expected","type":"type_error.str"}]}
```

However if I write the same code in Python, it works:

```
import requests
import os
import json

url = 'endpoint'
token='my token'

headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+token[:-1],
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
            }
res=requests.put(url, json='{"text":"whiteboard"}', headers=headers)
#res=requests.put(url, json='test string', headers=headers) # this also works
print('Response Content:\n',res)
```

What am I missing in the Perl code?

Comment: The Authorization token in the Python version is `"my toke"`. In the perl version it's `"my token"`. I don't think this is the root cause, but it is a difference.

Comment: Try printing [`$req->as_string`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request#$r-%3Eas_string) to see what's actually being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Perl is sending the JSON object `{"text":"whiteboard"}`. Python is sending the JSON string `"{\"text\":\"whiteboard\"}"`.

What the error is saying is the endpoint expects the body to be a JSON string, not a JSON object, so only the Python code works.

What you probably want is something like `$req->content(q["a string"])`. It's safer to encode it with a JSON encoder like in [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77276985/14660).

---

In your Perl code, `$req->content('{"text":"whiteboard"}')` just sends the string `{"text":"whiteboard"}` as the body.

In your Python code, `res=requests.put(url, json='{"text":"whiteboard"}', headers=headers)` serializes the string `{"text":"whiteboard"}` into JSON. The body is a single JSON string `"{\"text\":\"whiteboard\"}"`.

[From the docs...](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.put).

> json – (optional) A JSON serializable Python object to send in the body of the Request.

If you wanted to send a JSON object you'd pass it a Python dict.

```
res=requests.put(url, json={"text":"whiteboard"}, headers=headers)
```

This should result in the same error.

Comment: `$req->content(q["a string"])`. This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Perl equivalent would be

```perl
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

my $serializer = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->allow_nonref;

$req->content( $serializer->encode( '{"text":"whiteboard"}' ) );
```

---

According to the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) (search for `json=`),

```py
requests.put( url, json=payload )
```

is equivalent to

```py
import json

headers={ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
requests.put( url, data=json.dumps( payload ), headers=headers )
```

In other words, the value provided to `json` is encoded using JSON. This means the following is the body of the message sent by the Python script:

```json
"{\"text\":\"whiteboard\"}"
```

Comment: It is giving following error if I try your solution.
`hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this) at`

Comment: So use the `allow_nonref` option.